# Bibtex References list

Tags: bibtex

My reference list keeps doing weird things and I can't get it to stop. I don't like using the `\cite{blah blah}` command in my papers because I regard it as onerous, so I just type out my citations manually as I write. This means when I have to print my reference list from the bib file is use `\nocite{*}` . However, when I do this I get weird extra stuff that I don't want and I don't know where it's coming from. I'll show you want I mean.

In my document I have

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{project_bibli}
```

In my bib I have

```
@article{Acemoglu2001,
Author = {Acemoglu, Daron and Robinson, James A.},
Journal = {American Economic Review},
Keywords = {Conflict; Conflict Resolution; Alliances D74, Formal and Informal Sectors; Shadow Economy; Institutional Arrangements O17, Personal Income, Wealth, and Their Distributions D31, Capitalist Systems: Political Economy P16},
Number = {4},
Pages = {938 - 963},
Title = {{A Theory of Political Transitions}},
Volume = {91},
Year = {2001},
}
```

What I get when I combine everything

[Acemoglu and Robinson2001] Acemoglu, D. and Robinson, J. A. (2001). A Theory of Po- litical Transitions. American Economic Review, 91(4):938 – 963.

I want it not to show the [Acemoglu and Robinson2001] part. I have no idea how to get rid of it and it's driving me crazy. And yes, I've tried multiple `\bibliographystyle{---}` and it does it for all of them. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use  a style that doesn't add it. E.g. plain.